# ios interactivePopGestureRecognizer Edge slide

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

Callback method when the sliding operation when I did, I would like to know when I release the hand which is returned when the controller,

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: I have solve this problem.thank you